# How work this javascript arrow function and destructuring assignment code in tetris?

Tags: javascript, tetris

```js
class Piece {

    constructor() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    move(p) {
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
    }
}

let piece = new Piece();

const KEY = {
    LEFT: 'ArrowLeft'
}

const moves = {
    [KEY.LEFT]: (p) => ({...p, x: p.x - 1})
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (moves[event.key]) {  
        event.preventDefault();
    
        let p = moves[event.key](piece);
    
        piece.move(p);
        }
    }
});
```

I cannot understand how to move a piece.
piece is an instance of class Piece, to the best of my knowledge.

When variable `p` is declared, `moves[event.keyCode](piece)` is included, I don't know how this grammar works.

Especially this part.`[KEY.LEFT]: (p) => ({...p, x: p.x - 1})`

I'm wondering why there should be a : between [KEY.LEFT] and (p), and if there's no parentheses over the arrow function, the interpreter gets a grammar error. this. `'('{...p, x: p.x - 1}')'`

and `...p, x: p.x - 1` And what this means. I'm sorry it's such a basic grammar, but I don't know where I can ask questions.

I think I've tried something too difficult that doesn't fit my level..

Comment: That looks like basic JavaScript code. If you don't understand it, you should start with an introduction book or tutorial.

Comment: Are you just asking what [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is?  It's not clear what specifically you're asking.

Comment: `moves` is an object with a property named `ArrowLeft` (which is the value of `KEY.LEFT`) and that property is a function. So in the last line you just call a function providing a parameter `piece` which is not clear what it is from your question. As it's tetris `piece` probably describes the position of a square within the tetris grid, but that's guessing. Please provide more details to what actually is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moves[KEY.LEFT]` is a reference to a function. This function accepts `p` as an argument. You are passing `piece` to this function.

Within the function it applies the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to define a new object which is effectively a clone of the `piece` which was passed in, with the `x` property ameneded.

Here's an example of your original code using more readable syntax, which may make its logic clearer:

```
const moves = {
  'ArrowLeft': function(piece) {
    return {
      ...piece,
      x: piece.x - 1
    }
  }
}
```